# Proving that composition of permutation functions to the power of their orders is equal to identity function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have been asked to prove or disprove that for $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$, or permutation functions, it holds that: $(\sigma \circ \tau)^l=id$, where: k=ord($\sigma$),l=ord($\tau$).

I have a very strong feeling that this claim is true, but I can't find a way to prove it. I think that composition is not distributive in this case, right? so I can't split the composition with the powers.

I have a possible proof, and I was wondering if it is okay: let $r\in[n]$

$\left(\sigma\left(\tau\left(r\right)\right)\right)^{kl}=\left(\left(\sigma\left({\tau\left(r\right)}\right)\right)^{k}\right)^{l}=\left(Id\left(\tau\left(r\right)\right)\right)^{l}=\left(\tau\left(r\right)\right)^{l}=Id\left(r\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $S_6$, $\sigma = (1 2) , \tau=(2 3 4)$ then, $\sigma \circ \tau =(1 2 3 4)$, so this gives a counter-example as $(1234)^6=(1234)^2=(13)(24)\neq 1$

Comment: Where have I gone wrong in my proof?

Comment: What do you mean by $((\sigma \tau)(r)) ^{kl}$? $ \sigma\tau(r) \in [n]$ so it's power doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

In the case that $\sigma, \tau\in \mathcal{S}_n$ are not disjoint, then this is not true as Nabakumar Bhattacharya has noticed. However, if $\sigma, \tau\in \mathcal{S}_n$ are disjoint with $o(\sigma)=l$ and $o(\tau)=m$, then it holds than 
$$o(\sigma \tau)=o(\tau\circ\sigma)=\text{lcm}(l,m)$$
Indeed, let $M=\text{lcm}(l,m)$, so there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $al=M=bm$. Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commute (due to they are disjoint), then 
$$(\sigma \tau)^M=\sigma^M\tau^M=(\sigma^{l})^a(\tau^m)^b=\text{id}^a\text{id}^b=\text{id},$$
so $r:=o(\sigma\tau)$ is a divisor of $M$.

Let's check that $\tau^r$. For all $j$ out of the support of $\tau$ we have that $\tau(j)=j$, so $\tau^r(j)=j$. If $j\in \text{supp}(\tau)$ then $j\notin \text{supp}(\sigma)$, since they are disjoint, so $\sigma(j)=j$, and then  $\sigma^r(j)=j$. Hence, 
$$j=\text{id}(j)=(\sigma^r\tau^r)(j)=\tau^r(\sigma^r(j))=\tau^r(j)$$
so $\tau^r=\text{id}$. In this case, you have also that $\sigma^r=\text{id}$ since 
$$\text{id}=(\sigma\tau)^r=\sigma^r\tau^r=\sigma^r\text{id}=\sigma^r$$
and you are done as $r$ is a multiple of $l$ and $m$, so it is of $M$.

Comment: Yes it follows from the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ moreover we can also use the fact that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commutes in that case.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post